# spark reading large file

Tags: memory-management, apache-spark

This may be a silly question. I want to make sure I understand this correctly.

When you in a huge file `(400GB)` into a cluster, where the collective executor memory is only around `120GB`, Spark seems to read forever. It doesn't crash, nor does it start the first map job.

What I think is happening is, Spark is reading thru the large file as streams, and start discarding the older lines when the executors run out of memory. This obvious can be a problem when execution of `.map` codes starts, as the executor jvm would be reading back the file from the beginning again. I am wondering though, whether Spark is somehow spilling the data onto the hard drive, similar to the shuffle spilling mechanism.

Notice, I am not referring to the cache process. This has to do with the initial read using 
`sc.textFile(filename)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`sc.textFile` doesn't commence any reading. It simply defines a driver-resident data structure which can be used for further processing.

It is not until an action is called on an RDD that Spark will build up a strategy to perform all the required transforms (including the read) and then return the result.

If there is an action called to run the sequence, and your next transformation after the read is to map, then Spark will need to read a small section of lines of the file (according to the partitioning strategy based on the number of cores) and then immediately start to map it until it needs to return a result to the driver, or shuffle before the next sequence of transformations.

If your partitioning strategy (`defaultMinPartitions`) seems to be swamping the workers because the java representation of your partition (an `InputSplit` in HDFS terms) is bigger than available executor memory, then you need to specify the number of partitions to read as the second parameter to `textFile`. You can calculate the ideal number of partitions by dividing your file size by your target partition size (allowing for memory growth). A simple check that the file can be read would be:

```
sc.textFile(file, numPartitions)
  .count()
```

Also, check this question: [run reduceByKey on huge data in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144106/run-reducebykey-on-huge-data-in-spark)

Comment: I would put enphasis on checking if an action is actually being invoked or not. In addition, it might be adequate to mention that different persisentce settings can be used, as shown [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence).

Comment: I can tell you all you are on the wrong track. There is a .saveTextFile at the very end of all the code, which acts as the action needed. I rewrote the code today, substituting DataFrame with plain old RDD, and everything works fine with same size data and cluster. I am now thinking, this is all related to the DataFrame code I wrote.

Comment: really hoping someone could answer this question. I am able find how cache works in Spark, but can't find any documentation explaining what happens when your initial read exceeds the total memory. Anyone?

Comment: Edited my response to talk about tuning InputSplit size to fit in executor memory. You could be a bit more polite when you are receiving free help.

Comment: thanks for the edited response. don't meant to be impolite, just don't want to mark something as answer if it missed the point.The new partition size response is more directed to the original problem.