# run reduceByKey on huge data in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running reduceByKey in spark. My program is the simplest example of spark:

```
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).repartition(20000).
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _, 10000)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

but it always run out of memory...

I 'm using 50 servers , 35 executors per server, 140GB memory per server.

the documents volume is :
8TB documents, 20 billion documents, 1000 billion words in total.
and the words after reduce will be about 100 million.

I wonder how to set the configuration of spark?

I wonder what value should these parameters be?

```
1. the number of the maps ? 20000 for example?
2. the number of the reduces ? 10000 for example?
3. others parameters?
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? It would be great to know the answer for such amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

It would be helpful if you posted the logs, but one option would be to specify a larger number of partitions when reading in the initial text file (e.g. `sc.textFile(path, 200000)`) rather than re-partitioning after reading . Another important thing is to make sure that your input file is splittable (some compression options make it not splittable, and in that case Spark may have to read it on a single machine causing OOMs).

Some other options are, since you aren't caching any of the data, would be reducing the amount of memory Spark is setting aside for caching (controlled with  with `spark.storage.memoryFraction`), also since you are only working with tuples of strings I'd recommend using the `org.apache.spark.serializer.
KryoSerializer` serializer.

Comment: you mentioned _make sure that your input file is splittable_ . How can i make sure if my .dat file on s3 is split table? I can post an other question in the forum if this aint the right thing to do.

Comment: posted a question here [.gz vs flatfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803668/spark-reading-gz-file-faster-than-flat-files-on-s3-flat-file-take-way-too-l)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a `partionner`, it can help to reduce the number of key per node, if we suppose that keys word weights in average 1ko, it implies 100Go of memory exclusively for keys per node. With partitioning you can approximatively reduce number of key per node by the number of node, reducing accordingly the necessary amount of memery per node.
The `spark.storage.memoryFraction` option mentioned by @Holden is also an key factor.